# How do I dynamically prevent ASP.NET view state from being validated or deserialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

Given some shared code that is executed on the `Init` phase and passed a reference to the page the request is being made to, how can I prevent the page's view state from being validated or deserialized?

I've tried the obvious approach of setting the page's `ViewStateMode` to `Disabled`, but view state validation still occurs.

In my specific scenario, I have a shared piece of code that knows view state validation is going to fail. I want to prevent the validation exception, as the user is going to be redirected at the beginning of the `Load` phase. The redirect is done by third-party code, and I don't know where it is going to redirect to, which prevents me from doing the redirect on `Init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only recourse is to set `EnableViewStateMac` to false, you're out of luck. ViewState validation is now mandatory.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/09/09/farewell-enableviewstatemac.aspx

Comment: @mason: I don't believe that protecting bad developers who don't know what they're doing is a good reason; I'm forced to implement a solution that only works correctly half of the time, because of this.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee I feel your pain having been in the exact same type of situation (I wanted to dynamically populate dropdownlist controls using ajax which caused mac validation failures). With that said implementing an extender or script control and/or an updatepanel should be a solid solution, I have used them multiple times in complex scenarios (including async iframes and uploading)